# Long frame jank with Electron

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, electron, janky

[image]

Made an Electron app running on Ubuntu with ReactJS and Redux, encountered the UI Jank that shown in timeline of attached pic. The jank always occurred when XHR got response and handled (or the same time that Dispatched action to re-render React UI), add ["componentShouldUpdate" checking](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html) the long frame is still there.

[Raw Timeline Data](https://gist.github.com/foreseaz/5db4ce74346aa2700680eeead9ca1386) might be helpful.

Any possible reasons for the case is helpful since I have been searching the issue for a week. Thanks in advance.